# Can the Tank Auth login View not be embedded in a header?

Tags: codeigniter, authentication, tankauth

The closest solution I've been able to find to my question is here: [Keep Tank Auth on every page in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064434/keep-tank-auth-on-every-page-in-codeigniter)

I'm wanting a quick login in the "header bar" across the top of my app. It's always present, and either shows a quick login (name/password/login button) or a quick logout (logged in name and a logout button).

After fiddling around, the main challenge with the Tank Auth code is that it seems to be built on the assumption that the login form is a always going to be a separate form by itself - i.e. lots of space to show captchas for registration, or password renewals, etc. In my case the "always present header bar" will have limited space.

Is there something I'm missing? The only option I can see available to me is to change the auth controller / login function quite significantly - maybe a separate quickLogin function?

Am I missing something?

[Edit]

Perhaps another approach would be to override my supplied (Tank Auth) Auth.php controller, specifically, the login function.

Answer (score 0):

The view is just a view - you don't have to use that one, you can make your own form anywhere & call the appropriate function. So it could be a flat header form or a modal, or any other html

You only require that the correct fields be present to pass to the login function

Comment: Yeah, but the view that is supplied with Tank Auth (login_form.php) posts to the auth controller. The auth controller has a lot of requirements. I can write my own view, but if I don't supply all the requirements, the auth.php controller login function is unhappy. Which is why I think the supplied controller needs an override.

Comment: I think you'll find a new view a lot easier than a new controller, but you can do as you like. The requirements aren't that great - you can really just take that code & re-style it where ever you want